# Overlay loader page avoid operate on elements on the page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm stuck on a problem that it seems simple but I cannot find a solution.
I would like to present a page with a loader that cover all the web page. Ok. After some time tha overlay disappear and reveal the elements of the page but I cannot operate on them. I work on the opacity style. Follow the code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Wait 3 seconds
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.body.style.overflow = "visible";
    document.getElementById("modalLoader").setAttribute("style", "opacity: 0;");
  });
});
```

```css
.loaderScreen {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  opacity: 1;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  transition: opacity 2s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="modalLoader" class="container-fluid loaderScreen text-center">
  <h3 class="animate-charcter">Web page is loading...</h3>
</div>
```

At this point I can operate on the elements of the page only if I set display:none on the "modalLoader" element.

What am I overlooking?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because, although the overlay is invisible, it's still sitting above the content and intercepting the user's input. To avoid this you need to remove the element when the transition on the `opacity` ends. You can use the `transitionend` event to do this.

Also note that your `setTimeout()` is missing the delay argument, but I presume this was just an oversight when transposing the question.

```js
const overlay = document.querySelector('#modalLoader');

// remove element when opacity transition ends
overlay.addEventListener('transitionend', e => e.target.style.display = 'none'); 

// fade element out after 3 seconds
setTimeout(function() {
  document.body.style.overflow = "visible";
  overlay.style.opacity = 0;
}, 3000);
```

```css
.loaderScreen {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  opacity: 1;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  transition: opacity 2s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="modalLoader" class="container-fluid loaderScreen text-center">
  <h3 class="animate-charcter">Web page is loading...</h3>
</div>

<input type="text" id="exmaple-element" />
```